# Reset(Undo) the add table row action JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

Each time the button is clicked, table row(s) will be added depends on user input. Im wondering what if user makes a mistake or change his mind, is there any way to reset(undo) the add table row action. Thanks in advance

```js
$('#add-row').click(function() {
  var $tbody, $row, additionalRows;
  var numNewRows = parseInt($('#insert-rows-amnt').val(), 10);

  if (isNaN(numNewRows) || numNewRows <= 0) {
    alert('Please enter number of injection');
  } else {

    $tbody = $('table#one tbody ');
    $row = $tbody.find('tr:last');
    var lastRowIndex=($row.index()==-1? 0:$row.index()) +1 ;
    additionalRows = new Array(numNewRows);
    for(i=0;i<numNewRows;i++)
    {
    additionalRows[i]=` <tr>
    <td>${lastRowIndex}</td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" style="width: 100px" name="vaccineid[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" style="width:160px"name="vaccinename1[]">       </td>
     </tr>`
      lastRowIndex=lastRowIndex+1;
    }
   
    $tbody.append(additionalRows.join());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" id="insert-rows-amnt" name="insert-rows-amnt" value="<?php echo $tam ?>" />
<button id="add-row" type="button">Add</button>
 <button  type="reset" name="reset" >Reset</button>

<table id="one">
  <tbody>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: use `.html()` to replace the current html in the table

Comment: create another butoon like reset and when user click on it start removing from the bottom row to the first row(one-by-one not all)

Comment: add a edit button and reverse your process get data from DB to html page and then update this data with your primary key references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `remove()` on reset button click to remove the rows added.

```js
$('#add-row').click(function() {
  var $tbody, $row, additionalRows;
  var numNewRows = parseInt($('#insert-rows-amnt').val(), 10);

  if (isNaN(numNewRows) || numNewRows <= 0) {
    alert('Please enter number of injection');
  } else {

    $tbody = $('table#one tbody ');
    $row = $tbody.find('tr:last');
    var lastRowIndex=($row.index()==-1? 0:$row.index()) +1 ;
    additionalRows = new Array(numNewRows);
    for(i=0;i<numNewRows;i++)
    {
    additionalRows[i]=` <tr>
    <td>${lastRowIndex}</td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" style="width: 100px" name="vaccineid[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" style="width:160px"name="vaccinename1[]">       </td>
     </tr>`
      lastRowIndex=lastRowIndex+1;
    }
   
    $tbody.append(additionalRows.join());
  }
});

$('[name="reset"]').click(function() {
  $('#one tr').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" id="insert-rows-amnt" name="insert-rows-amnt" value="<?php echo $tam ?>" />
<button id="add-row" type="button">Add</button>
 <button  type="reset" name="reset" >Reset</button>

<table id="one">
  <tbody>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/t14mszuc/1/

```js
$('#add-row').click(function() {
  var $tbody, $row, additionalRows;
  var numNewRows = parseInt($('#insert-rows-amnt').val(), 10);
 $('button[type="reset"]').attr('lastCount', parseInt($('#insert-rows-amnt').val(), 10));
  if (isNaN(numNewRows) || numNewRows <= 0) {
    alert('Please enter number of injection');
  } else {

    $tbody = $('table#one tbody ');
    $row = $tbody.find('tr:last');
    var lastRowIndex=($row.index()==-1? 0:$row.index()) +1 ;
    additionalRows = new Array(numNewRows);
    for(i=0;i<numNewRows;i++)
    {
    additionalRows[i]=` <tr>
    <td>${lastRowIndex}</td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" style="width: 100px" name="vaccineid[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" style="width:160px"name="vaccinename1[]">       </td>
     </tr>`
      lastRowIndex=lastRowIndex+1;
    }
   
    $tbody.append(additionalRows.join());
  }
});


$('button[type="reset"]').click(function(){
  var cnt = $('button[type="reset"]').attr('lastCount');
  for(var i=0; i<cnt; i++){
   $('table tbody tr:nth-last-child(' + (cnt-i) + ')').remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="insert-rows-amnt" name="insert-rows-amnt" value="<?php echo $tam ?>" />
<button id="add-row" type="button">Add</button>
 <button  type="reset" name="reset" >Reset</button>

<table id="one">
  <tbody>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

**Solution explain**
It will remove the last inserted rows not the entire rows (it's like undo)

Comment: Give me some time will provide you exact undo scenario code.

Comment: @tam .... Here you go with exact undo functionality  https://jsfiddle.net/t14mszuc/2/ . .. Please have a look and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try for this solution.

```js
$('#add-row').click(function() {
  var $tbody, $row, additionalRows;
  var numNewRows = parseInt($('#insert-rows-amnt').val(), 10);

  if (isNaN(numNewRows) || numNewRows <= 0) {
    alert('Please enter number of injection');
  } else {

    $tbody = $('table#one tbody ');
    $row = $tbody.find('tr:last');
    var lastRowIndex=($row.index()==-1? 0:$row.index()) +1 ;
    additionalRows = new Array(numNewRows);
    for(i=0;i<numNewRows;i++)
    {
    additionalRows[i]=` <tr>
    <td>${lastRowIndex}</td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" style="width: 100px" name="vaccineid[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" style="width:160px"name="vaccinename1[]">       </td>
     </tr>`
      lastRowIndex=lastRowIndex+1;
    }
   
    $tbody.append(additionalRows.join());
  }
});

$('#remove-row').click(function() {
  var $tbody, $row, additionalRows;
  var numNewRows = parseInt($('#remove-rows-amnt').val(), 10);

  if (isNaN(numNewRows) || numNewRows <= 0) {
    alert('Please enter number of injection');
  } else {

    $tbody = $('table#one tbody ');
    $row = $tbody.find('tr:last');
    var lastRowIndex=($row.index()==-1? 0:$row.index()) +1 ;
    additionalRows = new Array(numNewRows);
    for(i=0;i<numNewRows;i++)
    {
  $('table tr:last').remove();
    }
   
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" id="insert-rows-amnt" name="insert-rows-amnt" value="<?php echo $tam ?>" />
<button id="add-row" type="button">Add</button>
 
 <input type="number" id="remove-rows-amnt" name="remove-rows-amnt" value="<?php echo $tam ?>" />
<button id="remove-row" type="button">Remove</button>

<table id="one">
  <tbody>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks!